# Hyper-V virtual machine appears in PowerShell but not in Hyper-V Manager

Tags: windows-server-2012, hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2

Im trying to manage my Hyper-V virtual machine in Hyper-V Manager but they are not there. I can configure them in a drop down box but I cannot start them and stop them.

If I go to PowerShell and try to list them, they appear and I can stop and start them there.

How do I get my Hyper-V virtual machines to appear again in Hyper-V Manager?

Comment: It would help if you would specify the Hyper-V and the PowerShell version

Comment: Well, I did tag this Windows Server 2012...........It would be the ones included in Windows Server 2012 R2....

Comment: Are you using Hyper-V manager on the Hyper-V host, or from a remote host? And same question for PowerShell? It could be a remoting problem.

Comment: You have tags for multiple Windows versions, so it's a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Originally it was WS2012....To make it clearer, I added another tag with R2.

Comment: @longneck All local.

Answer (score 0):

It could be antivirus related. Configure AV exclusions for the following:

- Default virtual machine configuration directory (C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V)
- Custom virtual machine configuration directories
- Default virtual hard disk drive directory(C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual Hard Disks)
- Custom virtual hard disk drive directories
- Custom replication data directories, if you are using Hyper-V Replica
- Snapshot directories
- Vmms.exe (Note: This file may have to be configured as a process exclusion within the antivirus software.)
- Vmwp.exe (Note: This file may have to be configured as a process exclusion within the antivirus software.)

Then restart the HyperV management service, and hopefully they will reappear.

Comment: No antivirus installed.

Comment: It could be a corrupt XML file then. Take a look [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/135d1385-4b75-4737-80de-f8c517c25f8d/vm-not-appearing-in-hyperv-manager) - there is some useful information on checking the XML files and their symbolic links if necessary.

Comment: Surprised Microsoft hasnt released a tool to at least check and remake the symbolic links.

Comment: Did the symbolic link thing..........Now I have to wait for when we can restart the Hyper-V host.